# Property file dot separated key names

Tags: java, c#-4.0, properties

I just noticed that almost all the key values in property files are in dot separated names. 
     eg -some.key=some value 
Does anyone know why? Just asked out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no any specific reason for that but it's just for better understanding of programmers nothing else. you can also directly write key=value without using any kind of "some" :-)

Answer (score 12):

It's basically a convention that makes it easier to see what properties are related.

For example:

person.title="Title"
person.surname="Surname"
job.description="Some description"

It's easy to see which properties are related and, using a smart editor, you can then chose to only see the properties for person. A few IDE's and editors can even use this to add code completion for you, as you know you want to work with person, but might not remember the exact property.

We sometimes underestimate the power of readability, yet a convention like this makes it easy for anyone to add, edit or maintain these properties. This becomes very important when working in teams or when on-boarding juniors.

Comment: It is certainly a conventionalized form of cardinality notation for one-to-many relationships between property groups (e.g., person.name, person.age). In XML, it would be expressed as "<person><name/><age/></person" and similar in a database table "PERSON" with NAME and AGE columns. However, this format suffers from all of the canonical form problems such as in CSV files where the delimiter (dot) nor value separator (equals) cannot be part of the property key without escapes. XML solved this but there is a penchant nowadays for going backward to JSON and plain-text formats such as this.

Comment: @DarrellTeague - Yes, you are correct, there are some issues with it, but with it being more of a convention than a standard, I guess you are free to make your own adjustments. The penchant for going back to simpler is, if you ask me, a good thing, but then, I am a rather lazy developer! Thank you for your insights.